# Partializing fraction with 4th power for integration

Tags: fractions

How can I partialize the following fraction ? My query mainly lies with the term with 4th power . I want to use it in an integration problem .So , any clue to the dealing with integration will also be helpful...

$$\frac{2p}{(1-p)(1+p^{4})}$$

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh...Thank you. I've understood it.But , can you tell me how can I integrate the term with the 4th power...It would be helpful if you include it in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$1+p^4=(1+\sqrt 2 p+p^2)(1-\sqrt 2 p+p^2)$$can you finish now?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz...can you tell me how did you do it?

Comment: Oh... you made a perfect square.

Comment: Sure!$$1+p^4=1+p^4+2p^2-2p^2\\=(1+p^2)^2-(\sqrt 2 p)^2\\=(1+\sqrt 2 p+p^2)(1-\sqrt 2 p+p^2)$$

Comment: How can I integrate it ?

Comment: There you can write $1+p^4=(p+s_1)(p+s_2)(p+s_3)(p+s_4)$ where $s_j=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}+j\frac{\pi}{2})}$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz...What is this called?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?
$$\frac{2p}{(1-p)(1+p^{4})}=\frac a{1-p}+\frac{b+cp+dp^2+ep ^3}{1+p^4 }$$ Cross multiply to get
$$-(a+b)+ (b-c+2)p + (c-d)p^2+ (d-e)p^3+ (e-a)p^4=0$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici...How can I integrate the partialized fraction...It would be helpful for me ...

Comment: @NehalSamee. You must in fact use what Mostafa Ayaz answered.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution (+1)